# I suggest more contrast for questions tagged by interesting tags.

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Questions tagged by a tag included in my list of interesting tags are highlighed. That's great, but in the new design it's almost invisible. More contrast please!

Comment: I would also like to have slightly more contrast for uninteresting tags. I know that the point is to reduce their visibility, but currently, I cannot see them at all, even when I desire to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have darkened the interesting tag background and lessened the translucency of the ignored tag background.